# Why ioctl returns 0 while no device attached?

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, i2c

I have a raspberry pi with a motion sensor attached. When I run an ioctl() call, it always returns 0, regardless the motion sensor is attached or not?

ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, _DEVICE_Addr)

Comment: You mix a run-time problem with a build-time problem. The `ioctl` call returning zero is a run-time problem, the "undefined reference" is a build error. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to only ask about *one* of the problems (and post a new question about the other problem).

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. The `I2C_SLAVE` ioctl does not check whether the device exists. It does not communicate on the I2C bus at all. It just does some checks to know whether the address is already in use and then saves the client address for subsequent calls.

Unfortunately this is not documented, but you can read it in the code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.c#L401